# PHP 6 digit date code display in human readable format

Tags: php

I have a set of dates that are formatted like this...

```
197402
192201
184707
```

The first four digits represents the year and the remaining two the month.  I am trying to output these in this format

```
February 1974
January 1922
July 1847
```

I have tried passing it to the date function like this...

```
echo date ('F Y', 197402)
```

But this is giving me **January 1970** everytime so I assume I have misunderstood how the date function works,  can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use the [DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), you can create from a specific format, and then output to another.

As pointed out in the comments below, you also need to set the day to the first of the month, otherwise you'll get undesired results if the current day is greater than the number of days in the given month.

```
echo DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', 19470201)->format('F Y');
```

Comment: This answer will not work when the current date is February 29 (on leap years), because `DateTime::createFromFormat` defaults the day part to the current day. Your example gives me [March 1947](http://erefredag.se/screenshots/datetime-leap-year.png) when my system time is 2004-02-29.

Comment: ah good point, this could be rectified by setting the day to the first of the month, either in `createFromFormat` or by calling the `setDate` method

Answer (score 5):

You're getting "January 1970" as an output, because you tried to create a date from the *timestamp* `197402`, which is seconds from January 1st, 1970. If you output the full string from that (with seconds and whatnot), you'll see it's a valid timestamp, producing an actual date, but they all end up in the start of January 1970, see this [**online demo**](https://3v4l.org/vFe9V).

That format, YYYYMM, isn't a recognizable format for most functions. You need to split it up, if you *know* the format will be in that way - and use that data instead. You can use `substr()` to split the string, and then convert the numerical month to the string associated with that month, with the help of `date()` and `mktime()` (since you just specify the year and month).

The following snippet

```
$arr = [197402, 192201, 184707];

foreach ($arr as $v) {
    $year   = substr($v, 0, 4);
    $month  = substr($v, 4, 2);
    echo date("F Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 0, $year))."<br />"; // mktime() produces a valid timestamp based on just month and year 

    // Alternatively, drop mktime() and use strtotime() and create from a standard format, 
    // while specifying a date in the month (which won't matter to the output)
    // echo date("F Y", strtotime("$month/01/$year"))."<br />";
}
```

will output

> February 1974
>   January 1922
>   July 1847

---

**Alternatively**, you can use the DateTime class (which is *a lot simpler* to work with), and create from a given format with `date_create_from_format()`

```
foreach ($arr as $v) {
    echo date_create_from_format('Yh', $v)->format('F Y')."<br />";
}
```

This will generate the same output as above.

## References

- http://php.net/substr
- http://php.net/mktime
- http://php.net/date
- http://php.net/datetime.createfromformat

Answer (score 3):

As you are passing an int to date, it is considering it as a Unix Timestamp.
To create a date object from a predefined format, use `DateTime::createFromFormat`.

`echo DateTime::createFromFormat('Ym',198403)->format('F Y');`

results in
`March 1984`

Comment: This answer [may not work](http://erefredag.se/screenshots/datetime-leap-year.png) when the current date is February 29 (on leap years) and the date you are formatting is also in February.

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to add a day to it, e.g. just add "01" and then use strtotime to convert that into a unix timestamp, as the date() function expects a timestamp as the parameter.

e.g.

```
echo date('F Y', strtotime("19220101"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have text representation of dates in a non-standard format. First you have to parse them and convert them to timestamps (the number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC). The PHP function `date()` can work only with timestamps.

The best approach (as of 2017) is to use the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) PHP class for date & time processing:

```
foreach (array('197402', '192201', '184707') as $text) {
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ym', $text);
    echo($date->format('F Y')."\n");
}
```

The method [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) parses a string using the given format and creates a new `DateTime` object if the parsing succeeds. It is the OOP equivalent of `strtotime()` but smarter (because it can get hints about what date components to search in the input string.)

The method [`DateTime::format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) produces the text representation of a date using the provided format. It is the OOP equivalent of `date()`.

The OOP approach (the [`DateTime*` classes](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php)) is recommended (and better than the procedural approach) because has built-in support for timezones (the procedural date-time functions lack it.)